# I have a StackOverflow account but cannot answer questions here?

Tags: discussion

I thought this site is a part of Stack Overflow and that logins are to the same account? I wanted to answer a question here, but it is protected and I had to create a new account so do not have the '10' reputation to answer it.

Answer (score 9):

New users are only restricted from answering questions that have been "protected", and even existing Stack Exchange users with the 100 association bonus still must earn 10 reputation points on *this* site before answering a protected question.

Questions are protected when they attract so many views where they get a lot of "me too" type answers or answers that don't meet the guidelines described in the [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq).

We don't have many protected questions, but if there is one you want to answer, first, ask or answer a question on the site that isn't protected, and when you earn at least 10 reputation points, you'll be able to answer the protected question. Hope this helps!

As an aside, since you must earn 10 reputation points regardless of whether or not you have the association bonus, you may want to login to your Stack Overflow account, and then visit Workplace SE and login with that same account so they are associated. You'll have 101 reputation instead of just 1, which means you will have more privileges. However, as Jim G. mentions in his comment, this relies on you having at least 200 reputation on another Stack Exchange site.

Most importantly, I should add that we protect questions because new users typically don't understand our Q&A format. We're not a discussion forum, and we look for answers that focus on answering the question posed by the asker. For more information, you may want to check out our [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq) and [How to Answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) before getting started. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the same email for this account?  It is supposed to link to your main account and start you with 101 reputation here to get you past the "new user" restrictions.

Comment: I am permanently logged into Stackoverflow using Chrome and setting the cookies to 'remember me'. So I am surprised it asked me to login again.

Comment: Well, it is not working as you say. Now I tried again and used the same email as my Stackoverflow account and created a new account as it asked - I have just '1' reputation.

Comment: The 101 includes the association bonus, which you only get if you have 200 rep on another site.

Comment: If a question is protected then you have to have at least 10 rep on this site to answer a question.

Comment: @AnilP are you sure you tried to link them? It doesn't look like your accounts are associated correctly (you should be able to see the linked accounts when you go to your profile page).